# NSLog without new line

Tags: objective-c, newline, nslog

Is there any function that does what NSLog does but without the new line at the end?

Answer (score 9):

see this http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString

excerpted from that page:

```
void LogIt (NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format  arguments: args];
    va_end (args);
    printf ("%s\n", [string UTF8String]);
    [string release];
} // LogIt
```

just customize the printf to suit your needs

Comment: NSString cString is deprecated. Use NSString UTF8String instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use printf(), but the time won't be displayed, and you won't be able to use the "%@" sequence for objects.

That said, you can implement your own logging function, using printf(), and adding support for objects. You will need to know how to deal with C variable arguments.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some trick. use special unicode character like:`u00a0`

`NSLog(@"\n\n\n\u00a0")`

Comment: What does it do?