# Xcode console print formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, console

I have this method that when called:

```
- (void)showContent
{
NSLog(@" 0  1  2  3  4  5  6");
for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < columns; k++) {
        MDLog(@"[%c]", board[j][k]);
    }
    NSLog(@"");
}
NSLog(@"---------------------------------------------------");
}
```

That's supposed to create an empty 6 x 7 grid (for a game of Connect Four) that looks like this:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

---------------------------------------------------
```

However, the Xcode console doesn't print it that way at all. It displays each column vertically on top of one another. Other useful info is I have

```
int rows; // initializes to be 6
int columns; // initializes to be 7
char board[6][7];
```

Xcode prints it this way:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6

[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]

[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]

[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]

[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]

[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]

[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]

---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: pls add how xcode prints it ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri check now

Comment: is MDLog does same as NSLog do ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri yes, it's a macro. I just use it to get rid of timestamps from the console

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244707/nslog-without-new-line

Comment: @TejaNandamuri that worked. thanks! I'm not sure why NSLog wasn't working in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the string for each line and print it all at once.  Alternatively you could use printf().  printf() does not add a newline so it would create the desired outcome.

```
- (void)showContent
{
    NSLog(@" 0  1  2  3  4  5  6");
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
            printf("[ ]");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    NSLog(@"---------------------------------------------------");
```

}